# ros_numpy package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use the package ros_numpy
The code is in https://github.com/eric-wieser/ros_numpy
How can I install it on my machine

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270439/ros_numpy-package/) by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-07**:
In the future, please make sure your question adheres to our [Support Guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29). It's harder to help you if you don't.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-07**:
Also: ROS Answers is a beginners forum, so we're happy to help, but such simple things as installing packages is really something that has been asked and answered many times before and is documented. Please make the effort to search first and save us all the time to answer it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just as any other package that has been released:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-$release-ros-numpy
```

Where `$release` is the name of the ROS release that you have installed.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on 2020-01-29**:
This does not work for ROS Melodic

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-30**:
Which is to be expected, seeing as the package has not been released into Melodic.

See [ros_numpy](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_numpy) and [status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=numpy](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=numpy).

Note also I wrote:

> as any other package that *has been released*

**Comment by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on 2020-01-31**:
Understood. Your answer was written before Melodic was released, and is now outdated. This is not "to be expected" for anyone using any of the currently recommended ROS distributions in 2020.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-31**:
The "to be expected" part was responding to the fact that you stated it doesn't work for Melodic. That is certainly to be expected, as it hasn't been released for that version of ROS.

I don't really see how that would not be expected. No matter which version of ROS you are using: if a package has not been released for it, you cannot use `apt` to install it (on Debian/Ubuntu).